# FlowVisor Slices

Tags: sdn

Good day all!

I encountered a problem while I was running flowvisor In mininet. The same problem occurred

also when I tried running it on different VM (Ubuntu server 14.04). I was able to install and run flowvisor but when i tried creating a slice 'Blue', it was created successfully but wasn't showing up at the

run of the command '$fvctl -f /dev/null list-slices'  except the default slice 'fvadmin'.

I have been on this for couple of days now but to no avail. I attach the problem here should incase you have encountered such problem or you have any idea on how to resolve it. Everything is working fine except that am not able to see the successful slices and when i tried to add flowspace to the created slice, it keep saying 'such slice does not exist'.

I have not connected the flowvisor to remote controllers yet, was trying to solve the

issue of creating slices and flowspace first.

Connection between Mininet and FlowVisor is perfect.

Hope to hear from you if there is any solution from your end.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However, I have fixed it by changing the permission of the directory I have installed the flowvisor. for instance chmod 777 flowvisor---> in my case. I hope it helps you.

BRG
HG